# Jquery datatable plugin not working with gridview?

Tags: c#, asp.net, jquery-plugins

I am trying to use **`jquerydatatable plugin`** to the gridview.Data is getting bound in gridview but for some reason plugin is not working

I could not find out the exact reason but i am getting error in console as below.Is the problem in the script i have used or in the coding part?

```
TypeError: $(...).dataTable is not a function
Source File: http://localhost:3852/YouthPossibilities/jqDatatable.aspx
```

Heres my script i've use

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.dataTables.js" ></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.js" ></script>
<link href="css/demo_table.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#gdView').dataTable();           
    })
</script>
```

Heres the aspx code

```
 <asp:GridView ID="gdView" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" OnPreRender="gdView_PreRender">
        <Columns>
            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="FirstName">
                <ItemTemplate >
                    <asp:Label ID="lblFstName" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("FirstName") %>'></asp:Label>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="LastName">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:Label ID="lblLstName" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("LastName") %>'></asp:Label>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Organization">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:Label ID="lblOrg" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Organization") %>'></asp:Label>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
        </Columns>            
    </asp:GridView>
```

Here's my c# code for binding the gridview

```
    List<gdViewBAL> lstgdviewBAL = new List<gdViewBAL>();
    gdViewDAL clsgdViewDAL = new gdViewDAL();
    DataTable dt = clsgdViewDAL.GetData();
    if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)
    {
        foreach (DataRow dRow in dt.Rows)
        {
            gdViewBAL clsgdviewBAL = new gdViewBAL();
            clsgdviewBAL.Cellphone = dRow["CellPhone"].ToString();
            clsgdviewBAL.Email = dRow["Email"].ToString();
            clsgdviewBAL.Firstname = dRow["FirstName"].ToString();
            clsgdviewBAL.Lastname = dRow["LastName"].ToString();
            clsgdviewBAL.Organization = dRow["Organization"].ToString();
            clsgdviewBAL.State1 = dRow["State1"].ToString();
            clsgdviewBAL.Zip1 = dRow["Zip1"].ToString();
            lstgdviewBAL.Add(clsgdviewBAL);
        }
        gdView.DataSource = lstgdviewBAL;
        gdView.DataBind();
        gdView.UseAccessibleHeader = true;
        gdView.HeaderRow.TableSection = TableRowSection.TableHeader;
        gdView.FooterRow.TableSection = TableRowSection.TableFooter;
```

Answer (score 1):

The reason is because you are using an ASP .NET generated ID in your JavaScript. This will not work as ASP .NET adds information to its ids. In order to do this, you need to tell ASP .NET not to add the extra information by adding the `ClientIDMode="Static"` attribute.

Try this:

```
<asp:GridView ID="gdView" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" OnPreRender="gdView_PreRender" ClientIDMode="Static">
```

Comment: In Chrome, if you right click and Inspect the grid, what is its id now?

Comment: Im not using chrome but in ff im getting the id as gdView